# Cost of Enabling Webpack Source Maps in Production

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have been reading about enabling source maps in production. Webpack recommends it [itself](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/). But what is the cost associated ; in terms of performance and not the build time ? Does the browser end up downloading all the maps over HTTP ( I could not find the calls under the network tab , but the code was available for debugging ). All the HTTP calls that download the map should be a concern if I have understood it correctly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you're using a source map setting that produces a separate source map file (check [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) which source map settings are suitable for use in production environments), the browser will only load them if source map downloads are enabled (at least on Chrome it's a configurable option, I don't know about other browsers) *and* the developer tools are open.

So, for regular visitors of your website, there won't be a noticeable performance impact.